# MIxing variable with html in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML list item that I want to display to my webpage using javascript/jquery. I looped through an array and I want to display the elements of the array in a HTML list using javascript but I can't just get it to work. Anyone with an idea of what's wrong with my code...

```
for (m = 0; m < myArray.length; m++){
      $("ul").append("<li>"+myArray[m]+"</li>");
}
```

Comment: The code provided above should work, Share the complete code including HTML

Comment: Try to define `var m=0`

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide functional example which people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: My guess.... you are calling this code before the ul is rendered. What does `console.log($("ul").length)` show? Probably need to wrap it in document.ready or place the script at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = ['apple', 'mango', 'banana'];

for (var m = 0; m < myArray.length; m++){
      $("ul").append("<li>"+myArray[m]+"</li>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a one-liner?

```js
var myArray = ['apple', 'mango', 'banana'];

$('ul').html("<li>"+myArray.join("</li><li>")+"</li>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Using join() you can stringify an Array with a selector of your choice.

**EDIT:** It is also less resource intensive because it injects the HTML all at once and not in a loop. And we all know that DOM manipulation needs the most resources.